# Android external database sqlite + GreenDao

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I'm having a problem trying to import my sqlite database using GreenDao library. It's empty. How can I do it?

In my external library I have one table box.
I have also generated Box class using gradle + MyDaoGenerator.

On application create:

```
DataBaseHelper helper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
```

---

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "MyDatabase";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * Конструктор
     * Принимает и сохраняет ссылку на переданный контекст для доступа к ресурсам приложения
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 3);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Создает пустую базу данных и перезаписывает ее нашей собственной базой
     * 
     */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //ничего не делать - база уже есть
        } else {
            //вызывая этот метод создаем пустую базу, позже она будет перезаписана
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Проверяет, существует ли уже эта база, чтобы не копировать каждый раз при запуске приложения
     * @return true если существует, false если не существует
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //база еще не существует
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

   /**
    * Копирует базу из папки assets заместо созданной локальной БД
    * Выполняется путем копирования потока байтов.
    * 
    */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Открываем локальную БД как входящий поток
        InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        //Путь ко вновь созданной БД
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Открываем пустую базу данных как исходящий поток
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //перемещаем байты из входящего файла в исходящий
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //закрываем потоки
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        //открываем БД
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    // Здесь можно добавить вспомогательные методы для доступа и получения данных из БД
    // вы можете возвращать курсоры через "return myDataBase.query(....)", это облегчит их использование
    // в создании адаптеров для ваших view
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Have you tried to track down what part of your code is not working correctly?

Comment: are you running this code before initialising the greendao db ?